# Checking for the JWT expiration in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have created these contexts to handle logging users in and retrieving the logged user to any component that might need it.

Here they are:

`context.js`

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";
import { AuthReducer, initialState } from "./reducers";

const AuthStateContext = React.createContext();
const AuthDispatchContext = React.createContext();

export function useAuthState() {
  const context = React.useContext(AuthStateContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useAuthState must be used within a AuthProvider");
  }

  return context;
}

export function useAuthDispatch() {
  const context = React.useContext(AuthDispatchContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useAuthDispatch must be used within a AuthProvider");
  }

  return context;
}

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, dispatch] = useReducer(AuthReducer, initialState);

  return (
    <AuthStateContext.Provider value={user}>
      <AuthDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </AuthDispatchContext.Provider>
    </AuthStateContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

`reducers.js`

```
let user = localStorage.getItem("currentUser")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser")).user
  : "";
let token = localStorage.getItem("currentUser")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser")).token
  : "";

export const initialState = {
  userDetails: user || "",
  token: token || "",
  loading: false,
  errorMessage: null,
};

export const AuthReducer = (initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "REQUEST_LOGIN":
      return {
        ...initialState,
        loading: true,
      };
    case "LOGIN_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...initialState,
        userDetails: action.payload.user,
        token: action.payload.token,
        loading: false,
      };
    case "LOGOUT":
      return {
        ...initialState,
        userDetails: "",
        token: "",
      };

    case "LOGIN_ERROR":
      return {
        ...initialState,
        loading: false,
        errorMessage: action.error,
      };

    default:
      throw new Error(`Unhandled action type: ${action.type}`);
  }
};
```

`actions.js`

```
const ROOT_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_HOST_URL;

export async function loginUser(dispatch, loginPayload) {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(loginPayload),
  };

  try {
    dispatch({ type: "REQUEST_LOGIN" });
    let response = await fetch(`${ROOT_URL}/auth/login`, requestOptions);
    let data = await response.json();

    if (data.user) {
      dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", payload: data });
      localStorage.setItem("currentUser", JSON.stringify(data));
      return data;
    }

    dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_ERROR", error: data.errors[0] });
    return;
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_ERROR", error: error });
  }
}

export async function logout(dispatch) {
  dispatch({ type: "LOGOUT" });
  localStorage.removeItem("currentUser");
  localStorage.removeItem("token");
}
```

my question is how to expand this to check whether the JWT has expired or not every time the `useAuthState()` hook is called (if this is even the best way to go about things)? and then log the user out or perhaps refresh the token from the server without having to log the user out if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

With JWT, you can decrypt your own token in a browser without a secret key. This way you can check if the JWT token is about or already expired. The secret key is only needed for the authenticity of where it's signed off. This is demonstrated well in [JWT website](https://jwt.io/).

If you wanted to be able to regenerate the key from expired JWT you can just set `ignoreExpiration` to `true` in [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)'s `verify()` function at your server, but then why even bother setting expiration time in the first place? It's best to only allow regenerating JWT when it's about to expire.

Comment: thank you, but, where do you think I should add this, given my code?